# No Application.class is in destination directory. Application could not be found in the registry

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to learn simplistic way of creating, running and exporting Eclipse RCP application. I am creating sample applications from wizards and trying to wrap it into product and export.

My efforts are described here: [How to make RCP application really standalone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646515/how-to-make-rcp-application-really-standalone)

My final state is characterized by following properties:

1) Destination directory DOES NOT contain my `Application.class` file, including inside any archives.

2) If running `eclipse.exe` the following error occurs: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "MyApp2.application" could not be found in the registry. The applications available are: org.eclipse.equinox.app.error.`

My questions are: should compiled java class files present in destination directory? I expect that definitely YES, but why doesn't Eclipse put them there???

Answer (score 0):

A product always point to one Appliction class.
http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseProductDeployment/article.html