# How to make simplistic RCP application really standalone?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

This is total refactoring of [my old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646515/how-to-make-rcp-application-really-standalone) on new level of knowledge.

**Questions summary**

My eclipse product is not working. Does it require any additional feature?

**Creating Simplistic RCP Application**

[image]
[image]
[image]

At this moment all wizard features were disabled and I press `Finish` button. As a result, Eclipse creates nearly empty project with `MANIFEST.MF` and `build.properties` files only.

[image]

Now I am creating an application. Application is an extension to `org.eclipse.core.runtime.applications` extension point, which is implemented inside `org.eclipse.core.runtime` plug-in. So I add this plug-in as a dependency:

[image]

This creates new node in `Package Explorer`, called `Plug-in Dependencies`:

[image]

Now I add new extension to this point in my plug-in:

[image]

I am giving an id `myappid` to my application and assign a class `myproject.Application` to it.

This creates a file `plugin.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>
   <extension
         id="myappid"
         point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.applications">
      <application
            cardinality="singleton-global"
            thread="main"
            visible="true">
         <run
               class="myproject.Application">
         </run>
      </application>
   </extension>

</plugin>
```

which contains all this information. Also this file is referred from `build.properties`:

```
source.. = src/
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
               .,\
               plugin.xml
```

Simultaneously `MANIFEST.MF` becomes invalid, since it is now required to be singleton, which is set either automatically, or by check box from `Overview` tab:

[image]

Note, that although my application id is `myappid`, this name is not fully qualified. Fully qualified name appears from concatenation between plug-in id and this is. In my case it is `myproject.myappid`.

Now I am going (back) to `Extensions` tab of manifest editor, and create class file for application by clicking `class` hyperlink:

[image]

This invokes `New Java class` wizard and finally creates `java` file and opens it in the editor:

```
package myproject;

import org.eclipse.equinox.app.IApplication;
import org.eclipse.equinox.app.IApplicationContext;

public class Application implements IApplication {

    @Override
    public Object start(IApplicationContext context) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

I am adding only one line here, inside `start` method:

```
System.out.println("Hello world from myproject");
```

Now after saving all I am able to run application from `Overview` tab of manifest editor. Program works and prints what is expected:

> Hello world from myproject

Printing occurs in Eclipse Console View.

**Creating Product Configuration**

Now I am creating a product configuration, which is required for export wizard can work.

[image]
[image]

Creating and setting product file simultaneously adds extension to `plugin.xml` file to `org.eclipse.core.runtime.products` extension point.

On the `Overview` tab of product file editor, I press `New` button, which invokes `New Product Definition` window:

[image]

I filled it with new product name, product id and also referred application, which fully qualified name I derived before.

Now my `plugin.xml` file lokks like follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>
   <extension
         id="myappid"
         point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.applications">
      <application
            cardinality="singleton-global"
            thread="main"
            visible="true">
         <run
               class="myproject.Application">
         </run>
      </application>
   </extension>
   <extension
         id="myproductid"
         point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.products">
      <product
            application="myproject.myappid"
            name="MyProduct">
      </product>
   </extension>

</plugin>
```

You see that our product is represented there.

Now I need to do a trick which I was not able to find for a long time.

Despite the fact that product file refers to application and plugin correctly, it is not included into product content automatically. I regard this as Eclipse bug.

So, I go to `Dependencies` tab of product file editor, and add my own plugin to it:

[image]

After that I need to press magic button `Add Required Plug-ins`

[image]
[image]

Now I am able to run my application from within `Overview` panel of product file editor and it works as expected (printing text inside console view).

**Exporting Product**

Only now I am able to utilize export wizard

[image]
[image]

This will create directory `D:\myproject` and put everything into it. It can be ran by running `eclipse.exe` inside

[image]

Unfortunately, it does nothing, although, cause no exceptions.

**Questions**

1) Why my exported program does nothing? Does it require eclipse console or something? Or it just doesn't work?

2) How to make the program to print? Is it possible to provide GUI console like in Eclipse? Or is it possible to force it to print to operating system terminal/console?

Comment: Are you sure it does nothing, did you try running it from the command line?

Comment: Yes, I tried running from command line. Did you? Has it printed for you?

Comment: On a Mac this needs to be run from a command line and prints its output in the command line window. I would expect Windows to be the same.

Comment: It does not work for me.

Comment: @SuzanCioc What was the problem? Could you reference some code examples?

Comment: Why not just choose Yes when asked "Would you like to create a 3.x rich client application" in the second step of the project creation wizard?

Answer (score 0):

1) Check you environment, especially JAVA_OPTS. If there's anything there, unset the variable and try running again

2) Check the JDK on your path with "java -version". Is it a 1.7.0 version (as specified in the execution environment) and does it match the eclipse launcher (i.e. if you are using 64-bit eclipse, it should be a 64-bit JDK and not a 32-bit one, and vice-versa). If there is a mismatch, fix (set PATH / JAVA_HOME to proper location and retry running). Note that on Windows the default JRE may be configured in the registry and your path may be clear. Check the Java settings in Control Panel to see what's the preferred one. Heck, even better, don't risk it: add the following lines in eclipse.ini instead, pointing to the correct JDK location, ABOVE the -vmargs line:

```
-vm
C:\path\to\the\proper\jdk\bin\javaw.exe
```

3) Look in the folder "configuration/.log" (timestamp is a UNIX long). Sometimes when a workspace doesn't get created Eclipse will log errors there...

4) Try running with "eclipse -consoleLog"

P.S. I haven't actually tried your steps, but the above is the list of things that have bitten me in the past (with 2 being the most common one)... :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think your program works correctly, but you are not seeing anything because the output is not directed anywhere.
Please edit the file eclipse.ini and add two options before the vmargs:

> -console
>
> -consoleLog

Then open a terminal/command interpreter in the folder and execute:

> eclipse

Then see whether there is still no output.